# Change Units in Calculation

Tags: calculations, lengths, units, unit-of-measure

Quick question. I'm looking for a way to change the units of a length while performing a calculation. I'm currently using the `ragged2e` package and trying to adjust `\setlength{\RaggedRightRightskip}{0em plus L}` where I want `L` to equal a fraction of the `\textwidth` in `ems`. I want the units in `ems` so that the value of `L` scales with the font size.

Edit: I want to perform an arithmetic calculation, but change the units after performing the calculation.

Comment: what do you mean by "a fraction in em" ? if you want (say) half `\textwidth` you can use `0.5\textwidth`   how would you use any unit?

Comment: if 1em is 10pt in the current font `\setlength{\RaggedRightRightskip}{2em}` is `\setlength{\RaggedRightRightskip}{20pt}` it does not have a value that varies with the font

Comment: I'm worried about using the same \RaggedRightRightskip length in both the main document body and in smaller parboxes and minipages. If I'm understanding correctly, using ems (or exs) instead of a fixed unit such as pt/in/cm will not scale the length in proportion to the font size.

Comment: length registers have no unit they are actually just integers, interpreted as a number of `sp` scaled points.

Comment: I'm just noting that the ragged2e documentation uses ems as a length in its default settings. See page 5. https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/ragged2e/ragged2e.pdf

Comment: yes as in my example above you can use em but it makes a fixed length not a variable length that changes with the font.  you can use cm or em or in or all three at once, the saved value is just a length no record of units is saved in the length register.

Comment: apart from tex syntax I still can not guess what you mean by "here I want L to equal a fraction of the \textwidth in ems"  what does a fraction of a length in any unit mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
\setlength{\RaggedRightRightskip}{0pt plus 3em}
```

or whatever factor instead of 3, the value of the em is taken from the font that's current at the time the setting is done; the length of 3em is transformed into points (actually into scaled points, but it doesn't matter).

You may want to define your own command

```
\newcommand{\myRaggedright}{%
  \setlength{\RaggedRightRightskip}{0pt plus 3em}%
  \RaggedRight
}
```

so the stretchability will be reset in terms of the current font.

But “a fraction of the textwidth in em” makes little sense, sorry. Let's see.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fpeval{round(\textwidth/(1em),5)}

\footnotesize

\fpeval{round(\textwidth/(1em),5}

\end{document}
```

This produces 34.49995 for normal size and 40.58765 for footnotesize.

Say you want to take 1/25 of these chunks and set the length in em units, then you get 13.8pt in either case, which is 1/25 of the text width. Yes, you divided by the em and multiplied by the em. They cancel each other.